# How can\should I test a conditional validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and RSpec 2. I would like to know how I can\should run test for the following validation mathod:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :firstname, :unless => :condition,
    :presence => true,
    ...
end
```

I mean the `:unless => :condition` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating objects that meet or don't meet the condition and seeing if they're valid/invalid.

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming you have been using [shoulda matchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/Shoulda/Matchers/ActiveModel) on Active Model to test such validations.

In that case, you can always control what instance you testing the validation on by using the "subject" block before your should "assertion" like: (for the :unless case)

```
context "testing validations" do
  subject do
    #Create object satisfying :condition
  end
  should_not validate_presence_of :first name
end
```

and the object case of the above.